# How to attach an xsd file to xml in .net?

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I have one xsd file having definition of two tables suppose A and B, and i want to create two files as A.xml and B.xml.

When i enter the data in these xml files data should validate with xsd

My question is

how can i validate the data while entering data in xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to gain Visual Studio Intellisense for editing these XML files in the Visual Studio IDE?

If so, place the schema in the same Visual Studio project that contains the XML files you want to edit, or place your schema centrally in the `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio _.0\Xml\Schemas` folder.

Be sure to define the targetNamespace within the schema and use an `xmlns` declaration to reference this target namespace from your XML document.

```
<Element xmlns="http://your/schema/target/namespace/here">
    <Element />
    <Element />
</Element>
```